# ubuntu 20.04 freeze when compiling kernel modules

Tags: virtual-machine, kernel-module, ubuntu-20.04

I'm using ubuntu20.04 in vmware workstation. I allocate 8 cpu cores, 6G RAM, 4G swap and enough free disk space(at least 25G) to ubuntu20.04. But after running make modules -j4 for about 30 minutes the whole system freezes. The only thing I can do is moving the cursor in virtual machine, the click doesn't get response. When I click "hang up the vm" I get error "cannot hang up vm". After trying several times I can hang it up successsfully. And after I press "continue vm" vm works again but after running about 30 min the situation just occurs again.

gcc version, kernel version are listed below:(they are both compiling linux-4.8.5 kernel source code)

```
user@ubuntu:~$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
user@ubuntu:~$ uname -r
5.15.57


user@centos7:~$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
user@centos7:~$ uname -r
5.15.86
```

syslog when the freeze situation occurs:

```
Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:55:37 ...
 kernel:[ 7665.562563] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:55:37 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.562563] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:55:37 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.562667] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.564688]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.564982] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565049] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565083] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565393] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565437] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565441] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565443] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565446] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565448] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565450] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565452] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565455] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565458] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565486] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565515]  <TASK>
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565669]  irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565844]  irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565848]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4e/0x90
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565852]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1a/0x20
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565886] RIP: 0033:0x12cfc00
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565972] Code: 33 ff ff ff 83 e6 01 48 89 df e8 4b 0c ff ff 85 c0 0f 84 29 ff ff ff 80 bb 9c 00 00 00 53 0f 85 19 ff ff ff e9 6a ff ff ff 90 <4c> 89 e0 5b 5d 41 5c c3 48 8d 15 c2 3a 79 00 be 1d 0a 00 00 48 8d
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565974] RSP: 002b:00007ffd36e8a930 EFLAGS: 00000246
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565977] RAX: 0000000002569580 RBX: 00000000023c0a00 RCX: 0000000000000005
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565979] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000000241dcf0 RDI: 00000000023c0a00
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565980] RBP: 00000000023c0a98 R08: 000000000000000f R09: 00007fc50177c000
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565981] R10: 0000000002569580 R11: 0256958002569580 R12: 000000000241dcf0
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565983] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007ffd36e8a978 R15: 00007fc5007b8f00
Jan 26 18:55:47 ubuntu kernel: [ 7665.565986]  </TASK>

Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:56:06 ...
 kernel:[ 7693.578970] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 48s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:56:06 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.578970] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 48s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.578983] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579073]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579088] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579093] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579135] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579146] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579149] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579152] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579154] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579155] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579157] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579159] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579161] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579163] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579165] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579169] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:56:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7693.579172]  <TASK>
(same as above)
 </TASK>

Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:56:40 ...
 kernel:[ 7729.590239] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 81s! [cc1:100337]

Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:57:09 ...
 kernel:[ 7757.599000] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 107s! [cc1:100337]

Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:57:36 ...
 kernel:[ 7785.607641] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 133s! [cc1:100337]

Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:58:27 ...
 kernel:[ 7813.614515] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 159s! [cc1:100337]

Message from syslogd@ubuntu at Jan 26 18:58:32 ...
 kernel:[ 7841.620739] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 186s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812787] rcu: INFO: rcu_sched self-detected stall on CPU
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812875] rcu:      6-....: (1 GPs behind) idle=2df/1/0x4000000000000000 softirq=645654/645656 fqs=31
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812919]   (t=15001 jiffies g=1424273 q=363)
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812947] rcu: rcu_sched kthread starved for 509 jiffies! g1424273 f0x0 RCU_GP_WAIT_FQS(5) ->state=0x0 ->cpu=5
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812954] rcu:      Unless rcu_sched kthread gets sufficient CPU time, OOM is now expected behavior.
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812956] rcu: RCU grace-period kthread stack dump:
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.812957] task:rcu_sched       state:R  running task     stack:    0 pid:   14 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813009] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813013]  <TASK>
(same as above)
</TASK>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813330] rcu: Stack dump where RCU GP kthread last ran:
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813359] Sending NMI from CPU 6 to CPUs 5:
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813681] NMI backtrace for cpu 5
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813684] CPU: 5 PID: 843 Comm: gmain Tainted: G
   L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813688] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813690] RIP: 0010:native_write_msr+0x6/0x30
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813761] Code: fc ff b8 40 00 00 00 0f 00 d8 44 89 e7 e8 62 15 fc ff eb cb e8 fb d6 cc 00 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 89 f9 89 f0 0f 30 <66> 90 c3 cc cc cc cc 55 48 c1 e2 20 89 f6 48 09 d6 31 d2 48 89 e5
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813764] RSP: 0000:ffffc251805c0f00 EFLAGS: 00000007
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813767] RAX: 000000009437f6ed RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813768] RDX: 0000000000000cb4 RSI: 000000009437f6ed RDI: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813770] RBP: ffffc251805c0f08 R08: 0000000000000001 R09: 000007014874c7c1
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813771] R10: 7fffffffffffffff R11: ffffc251805c0ff8 R12: 000027a10367387b
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813772] R13: ffffa04af7f5fe00 R14: ffffa04af7f62db8 R15: ffffa04af7f62df8
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813796] FS:  00007f02c513e700(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813798] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813800] CR2: 00007f00d5bf2000 CR3: 0000000117928001 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813803] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813805]  <IRQ>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813848]  ? lapic_next_deadline+0x2c/0x40
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813936]  clockevents_program_event+0xa8/0x130
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813968]  tick_program_event+0x41/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813971]  ? hrtimer_update_next_event+0x4f/0x70
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813973]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x136/0x230
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813976]  __sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x5e/0xe0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813978]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7b/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813982]  </IRQ>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813983]  <TASK>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813983]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1a/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813986] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813989] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813991] RSP: 0000:ffffc2518434fed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813993] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813994] RDX: ffffa04a40339900 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc2518434ff58
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813995] RBP: ffffc2518434ff08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000070146c988c1
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813996] R10: 00000701468c7fc1 R11: 00000000000024d8 R12: ffffc2518434ff58
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.813998] R13: ffffa04a557ce400 R14: ffffa04a557ce400 R15: ffffa04a557ce400
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814000]  irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814004]  irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814007]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4e/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814011]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1a/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814013] RIP: 0033:0x7f02c5e07508
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814017] Code: c0 74 0f e9 4a f5 ff ff 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 c3 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 40 00 f3 0f 1e fa 31 f6 87 37 <83> fe 01 74 0b e9 ce f4 ff ff 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 c3 0f 1f 80 00 00
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814019] RSP: 002b:00007f02c513dc98 EFLAGS: 00000246
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814021] RAX: 0000000000000f6a RBX: 000000007fffffff RCX: 0000000000000004
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814023] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 000055920b115870
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814024] RBP: 0000000000000002 R08: 0000000000000002 R09: 0000000000000001
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814025] R10: 000055920b132e00 R11: 000055920b112580 R12: 0000000000000002
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814026] R13: 000055920b115870 R14: 000055920b112dd0 R15: 00007f02c513dcf4
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814028]  </TASK>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814382] NMI backtrace for cpu 6
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814389] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814393] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814394] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814395]  <IRQ>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814397]  dump_stack_lvl+0x4a/0x63
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814484]  dump_stack+0x10/0x16
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814487]  nmi_cpu_backtrace.cold+0x4d/0x96
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814491]  ? lapic_can_unplug_cpu+0x90/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814495]  nmi_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0xf3/0x100
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814594]  arch_trigger_cpumask_backtrace+0x19/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814598]  rcu_dump_cpu_stacks+0x132/0x16d
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814762]  rcu_sched_clock_irq.cold+0x100/0x36a
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814787]  ? account_system_index_time+0xa0/0xc0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814831]  update_process_times+0x94/0xd0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814861]  tick_sched_handle.isra.0+0x25/0x60
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814865]  tick_sched_timer+0x71/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814868]  ? tick_sched_do_timer+0x50/0x50
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814871]  __hrtimer_run_queues+0xc8/0x1d0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814873]  hrtimer_interrupt+0x109/0x230
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814876]  __sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x5e/0xe0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814878]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x7b/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814883]  </IRQ>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814883]  <TASK>
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814884]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1a/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814887] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814890] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814893] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814896] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814897] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814899] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814927] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814929] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814932]  irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814937]  irqentry_exit+0x1d/0x30
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814940]  sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x4e/0x90
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814943]  asm_sysvec_apic_timer_interrupt+0x1a/0x20
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814945] RIP: 0033:0x12cfc00
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814949] Code: 33 ff ff ff 83 e6 01 48 89 df e8 4b 0c ff ff 85 c0 0f 84 29 ff ff ff 80 bb 9c 00 00 00 53 0f 85 19 ff ff ff e9 6a ff ff ff 90 <4c> 89 e0 5b 5d 41 5c c3 48 8d 15 c2 3a 79 00 be 1d 0a 00 00 48 8d
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814951] RSP: 002b:00007ffd36e8a930 EFLAGS: 00000246
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814953] RAX: 0000000002569580 RBX: 00000000023c0a00 RCX: 0000000000000005
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814978] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000000000241dcf0 RDI: 00000000023c0a00
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814980] RBP: 00000000023c0a98 R08: 000000000000000f R09: 00007fc50177c000
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814981] R10: 0000000002569580 R11: 0256958002569580 R12: 000000000241dcf0
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814983] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 00007ffd36e8a978 R15: 00007fc5007b8f00
Jan 26 18:56:15 ubuntu kernel: [ 7702.814985]  </TASK>
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590239] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 81s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590249] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590369]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590381] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590385] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590387] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590394] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590397] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590400] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590402] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590403] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590405] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590407] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590409] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590411] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590412] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590451] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:56:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 7729.590453]  <TASK>
(same as above)
</TASK>
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599000] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 107s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599009] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599076]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599086] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599089] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599091] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599097] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599099] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599101] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599103] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599104] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599105] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599106] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599108] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599110] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599111] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:57:09 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599114] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:57:16 ubuntu kernel: [ 7757.599116]  <TASK>
(same as above)
</TASK>
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607641] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 133s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607651] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607750]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607760] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607764] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607765] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607772] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607774] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607776] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607777] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607779] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607780] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607781] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607782] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607784] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:57:36 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607785] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:57:59 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607788] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7785.607790]  <TASK>
(same as above)
</TASK>
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614515] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 159s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614524] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614588]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614635] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614638] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614640] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614646] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614648] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614650] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614652] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614653] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614654] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614656] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614657] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614659] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614660] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:58:27 ubuntu kernel: [ 7813.614686] Call Trace:
(same as above)
</TASK>
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620739] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 186s! [cc1:100337]
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620748] Modules linked in: btrfs ... hid_generic
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620818]  crc32_pclmul mptspi usbhid mptscsih ahci psmouse mptbase hid e1000 pata_acpi libahci scsi_transport_spi i2c_piix4
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620830] CPU: 6 PID: 100337 Comm: cc1 Tainted: G
    L    5.15.0-52-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620833] Hardware name: VMware, Inc. VMware Virtual Platform/440BX Desktop Reference Platform, BIOS 6.00 02/27/2020
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620835] RIP: 0010:exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0xea/0x1c0
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620842] Code: e3 02 75 71 fa 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 fb 01 00 48 8b 18 f7 c3 0e 30 02 00 0f 84 48 ff ff ff fb 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f6> c3 08 74 be e8 3c 23 c0 00 f6 c7 10 74 b9 4c 89 e7 e8 ff 49 13
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620844] RSP: 0000:ffffc251922e7ed8 EFLAGS: 00000202
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620847] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000008 RCX: 00000000000006e0
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620848] RDX: ffffa04a4033cb00 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620886] RBP: ffffc251922e7f08 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 000006f3506a78c1
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620888] R10: 000006f3502d6fc1 R11: 0000000000512638 R12: ffffc251922e7f58
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620890] R13: ffffa04a460d3200 R14: ffffa04a460d3200 R15: ffffa04a460d3200
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620891] FS:  00007fc500f3aac0(0000) GS:ffffa04af7f80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620893] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620895] CR2: 00007fc50060f000 CR3: 000000010b0ae004 CR4: 00000000003706e0
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620898] Call Trace:
Jan 26 18:58:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 7841.620900]  <TASK>
(same as above)
</TASK>
Jan 26 19:05:42 ubuntu NetworkManager[768]: <info>  [1674788384.3036] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
```

I encountered freezing once, by adding RAM I solved the problem. But this time I add RAM to 8G, freezing still occurs. What also confuses me is that my centos vm with 3G RAM and 8 cpu cores run `make modules -j8` successfully. I have no idea about the difference.

To check the cpu and memory usage I execute top at the same time. the picture is top's output when freezing occurs. [top command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08YUt.jpg)

Comment: Different kernels, different compilers, etc.

Comment: @0andriy thanks for comment. I updated the kernel version and gcc version info in my question description. And I solved the problem by rebooting and type `make modules` without `-j8` option. I'm not sure the solution can be called a `solution`...

Comment: v4.8.5 is **not** a Linux kernel version. Maybe you need to figure out what you are doing?

Comment: @0andriy sorry I didn't get what you mean, I just download the source code [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/linux-4.8.5.tar.gz)